# inheritance in c#

Tags: c#

what is the difference between

```
class abc : qwe
{  
}
```

and

```
class zxc : qwe
{  
    zxc() : base(new someAnotherclass()).  
    {
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference is, that in your first code snippet you're calling the parameterless base class constructor, whereas in your second code snippet you're calling the base class constructor with a parameter.

Your base class might be defined as follows:

```
class qwe{
    public qwe(){ /* Some code */ }

    public qwe(SomeAnotherclass ac){ /* Some other code */ }
}
```

The default constructor for your `abc` class looks exactly like the following:

```
class abc{
    public abc() : base() {}    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first is a class which base is `qwe`. The second is the same but it also have constructor that executes specified constructor (with diffrent arguments then default one) from base class while being invoked.

Second snippet shows how to handle the situation when base class do not have default constructor. The reason of that requirement is that derived class constructor is always calling base class constructor first. If base constructor needs some parameters then you have to call it explicetely.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to inheritance, both are the same: **zxc is_a qwe**

In your second example you simply define the empty zxc constructor to call the qwe constructor before with an argument you generate (someAnotherclass()). That usually means an aggregation if you keep the reference somewhere, not inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

The result will be the same.

By calling the constructor on zxc you can add some functionality AND call the base constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In the second code snippet, you are [chaining](http://www.csharp411.com/constructor-chaining/) the default (no parameter) constructor of the inherited to a constructor of the base class that takes a `someAnotherClass` parameter.

When initializing the zxc class, this will call the qwe constructor with the new `someAnotherClass`.

With the first code snippet, none of this constructor chaining is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you mean

```
class abc : qwe
{  
}
```

and

```
class zxc : qwe
{  
    public zxc() : base(new someAnotherClass()).  
    {
    }    
}
```

This mean that

```
class qwe
{
    // public constructor accepting SomeAnotherType 
    public qwe(SomeAnotherType someAnotherClass)
    {
    }
}
```

Such approach is called `nested constructor call` or `constructor chaining`